# PHP server not working on Mac terminal, what should I do?

Tags: php, macos, server, terminal, localhost

Tried to run the php server on a project I am currently working on and suddenly my browser says can not reach the server. In terminal the server seems to work fine but the browser can not load it. I checked if there was any bug on my project but there was not, it does this on all my projects.

[My terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMTBI.png)

[My web browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5l8q.png)

Comment: Have you tried running `php -S localhost:80`?

Comment: Usually you need to run things as root in order to bind ports below 1024. Does a higher port number work?

Comment: @NigelRen I run sudo php -S localhost:80 and worked fine! :)